# Overriding async method returning deferred in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, overriding, deferred, chaining

I have an asynchronous method `asyncInit` that is doing some async stuff and returning `Deferred`. Now I extend the module with another module that provides extra functionality and also nees asynchronous init, so I want to extend the method `asyncInit`.

If the `asyncInit` is not defined in other module, I just call my stuff, but if it is present, I need to call my stuff, and additionally the inherited stuff, and then resolve the deferred.

I've made that code template to achieve that:

```
asyncInit: function() {
 var def = new Deferred()
 var domystuff = function() {
    // do my stuff
    def.resolve()
 }
 if (this.inherited) {
  this.inherited().then(function(){
    domystaff()
  }, function(error){
    def.reject(error)
  })
 } else {
    domystaff()
 }
 return def
}
```

However, it's quite long and copy&paste it to every possible place doesn't seem a good solution.

Does dojo 'natively' solves the problem with overriding/extending functions returning `Deferred` or that complicated chain can be somehow moved to external function that can be called as one-liner?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the first thing to try is `asyncInit: firstModule.asyncInit,` in your second module.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 well, actually, if you want to keep the modules independent, they should be written in the way, that their initialization can happen in any order. In that case, I want `asyncInit` to accomplish both actions before `deferred.resolve`, no matter in which order.

Comment: Any other constraints not mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Roamer-1888, no, there are no constraints not mentioned in the question, this goes only about chaining inherited deferred call